# Display an Exact Date in JavaScript Regardless of TimeZone

Tags: javascript, date

I'm writing some simple code to display birthdays of some friends. I've got the birthdays stored in a JSON file and I'm pulling them in and initializing them as Date objects like so:

```
birthday: new Date(p.birthday)
```

Then I display those dates using moment to format them, like so:

```
let formatted = moment(birthdayDate).format(BirthdayFormat);
```

This applies an automatic local time zone, probably from when I set up the initial date object, and depending on the time of day might put the date a few hours in the past, thus changing the date to the previous day since it defaults to midnight.

Basically, I just want to display that date unchanging at any time since it's just stating that person's birthday and time zones aren't relevant at all. I use it elsewhere as a Date so I don't really want to store it in the JSON as formatted, so how can I set this up such that it just acknowledges the date and doesn't adjust it for a time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, the dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format. Unfortunately, ECMAScript parses such dates as UTC.

If the date has already been parsed as UTC, then you just need to display UTC values to your users. You can use momentjs's *utc* function (I guess this is one of its main uses):

```js
// Built-in parser treats YYYY-MM-DD as UTC
let d = new Date('2020-12-30');
// m inherits the same time value, so is also "UTC"
let m = moment(d);

// Include hour H in format to show effect of utc setting later
let birthdayFormat = 'dddd, D MMMM, YYYY [at] H';

// Default is local timezone, H reflects local offset
// Date might be 29 or 30, depends on whether offset is - or + respectively
console.log('Local: ' + m.format(birthdayFormat));

// Toggle UTC switch, all output will now be UTC, not local
m.utc();

// Values are now UTC, so offset is zero and so is H
// Displays Wednesday, 30 December, 2020 at 0 for all users
console.log('UTC  : ' + m.format(birthdayFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to the date string so that the date does not include the timezone specific value.

```
birthday: new Date(p.birthday).toDateString()
```

Then display with the momentjs

```
let formatted = moment(birthdayDate).format(BirthdayFormat);
```

Comment: Hmm this is still giving me the adjusted date in the final result:     
`const birthdayString = birthdayDate.toDateString();`
`let formatted = moment(birthdayString).format(BirthdayFormat);`

Comment: @muttley91 Can you try just `const birthdayString = p.birthday; let formatted = moment(birthdayString).format(BirthdayFormat);`

Comment: @muttley91 What is the value of p.birthday?

Comment: p.birthday is a string like so: `"1985-10-03"` but these are in separate spots in the code so that's already a Date by the time it gets to the formatting part.